# AWS Cloudwatch synthetics - how to install external dependencies for runnning canaries

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a python selenium script that needs a third party library ('redis' package for instance).
I would like to run this script as an AWS cloudwatch synthetic canary. But it fails because it does not have this library installed.

So far I did not find in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries.html), nor in the AWS UI console how to `pip install` dependencies before executing the canary. Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use external dependencies, but [you must package them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_WritingCanary_Python.html#CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_WritingCanary_Python_package) yourself into a single `.zip` file, along with the script itself.

Upload the `.zip` file to S3 and point Synthetics to it when you [create the canary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_Create.html).

Synthetics is picky about the `.zip` package structure.  Newer runtime versions are less strict, but the default folder structures are:

- [Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_WritingCanary_Python.html):  `python/my_canary_filename.py`
- [Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_WritingCanary_Nodejs.html):  `nodejs/node_modules/myCanaryFilename.js`

Comment: Where in the .zip should the Python dependencies go in order to be I'm portable? I've tried the root and within `python`, but neither works - the modules cannot be imported.

Comment: @scubbo If the accepted answer isn't working for you, consider asking a new question with a minimal reproducible example and error messages.  I don't want to make guesses, as there are too many hidden variables.

Comment: [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75750343/how-to-upload-dependencies-to-be-consumed-by-a-python-aws-synthetic-canary).

A helpful way to cut down on some hidden variables would be to link to a working implementation of your own, that I can compare with mine.