# How to upload dependencies to be consumed by a Python AWS Synthetic ("Canary")?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

Referencing AWS documentation, especially [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_WritingCanary_Python.html), and StackOverflow answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74973455/aws-cloudwatch-synthetics-how-to-install-external-dependencies-for-runnning-ca), I would have expected that simply including the dependencies in the uploaded `.zip` file would be sufficient - but that does not seem to be the case. Despite `os.listdir` showing that a module exists on a path that has been added to `sys.path`, the attempted import fails to find the module.

See my minimal reproduction (including log output in the `README.md`) [here](https://github.com/scubbo/awsSyntheticPythonImportMinimalRepro)

Comment: did you ever figure out the solution to this?